# Python/Bottle template weird behavior when generating html table

Tags: python, html, for-loop, html-table, bottle

I've followed few tutorials (bottle one as well), but my code ain't working as supposed to. Basically I'd like to have a html table generated in this way:

template is served in this way:

```
return template('template', data=result)
```

Snippet of code from my template:

```
%for item in data.data:
  %if ("X" in c_label and "Y" not in p_label and "Z" not in p_label):
  <tr>
    <td>{{child}}</td>
    <td>{{parent}}</td>
  </tr>
  %elif ("X" in c_label and "Y" in p_label):
  <tr>
    <td>{{child}}</td>
    <td>{{parent}}</td>
  </tr>
  %elif ("X" in c_label and "Z" in p_label):
  <tr>
    <td>{{child}}</td>
    <td>{{parent}}</td>
  </tr>
  %elif "W" in c_label:
  <tr>
    <td>{{child}}</td>
    <td>{{parent}}</td>
  </tr>
  %elif "U" in c_label:
  <tr>
    <td>{{child}}</td>
    <td>{{parent}}</td>
  </tr>
  %elif "Z" in c_label:
  <tr>
    <td>{{child}}</td>
    <td>{{parent}}</td>
  </tr>
%end
</table>
```

The problem is that python keeps running the `for` cycle even after `%end`. I've seen it in the generated page:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>U</td>
    <td>I</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>U</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <tr>
    <td>U</td>
    <td>I</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So for some reason it keeps ammending the `</table>` per each iteration which ofc totally screws the final page :).

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Comment: What's the templating engine? Do you have to end the if and the for separately? (I use Jinja2, and this would need two `end`s). Aside: you probably know this, but those blocks all do the same thing, so if this is your finished code, you could get rid of all the `if`s...

Comment: We'll need to see a more complete example that illustrates the problem.  I'm suspicious because `</table>` is present multiple times in your output, but is outside of the `for` loop in your template.  Something outside this snippet is relevant.

Comment: Hi all,it's SimpleTemplate engine:
[link]http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kwinkunks I've identified this as a SimpleTemplate engine.

The answere is here:
http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.11/stpl.html

e.g:

```
<div>\\
 %if True:
<span>content</span>\\
 %end
</div>
```

So as kwinkunks suggested, `if` must be ended with `end` as well.